# Python: how to get a number followed by a specific key word from a string

Tags: python, string

Let's say I have a string like this:

```
Benchmark\r\n\tRunning for engine innodb\r\n\tAverage number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMinimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMaximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tNumber of clients running queries: 1\r\n\tAverage number of queries per client: 2
```

If I'm only interested in the value followed by 'Average number of seconds to run all queries:', how can I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `split()` the string, and add the values to a dictionary. Then you can access all the values as desired.

```
a = Benchmark\r\n\tRunning for engine innodb\r\n\tAverage number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMinimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMaximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tNumber of clients running queries: 1\r\n\tAverage number of queries per client: 2
lst = a.split("k\r\n\")
d = {}
for i in z[2:]:    
    k,v = i.split(":")
    d[k] = v
```

Or also

```
d = dict((k,v) for k,v in (i.split(':') for i in a.split("\r\n\t")[2:]))
```

Now you can access all the values if you want by doing

```
d["Average number of seconds to run all queries"]
>>>' 0.374 seconds'
```

Answer (score 1):

One overkill of this problem is to use the regular expression since the regular expression is a general approach to deal with the patter matching.

For example, You can use the following code to solve your problem here:

```
import re
mystring = 'Your input'

float_pattern = '(\d*\.\d*)'
prefix = 'Average number of seconds to run all queries: '
postfix = ' seconds'
all_time = re.findall(prefix+float_pattern+postfix,mystring)
all_time_t = map(lambda x:float(x),all_time)
average_time = sum(all_time_t)/len(all_time_t)
```

Read the document for regular expression for more information:https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

My solution's very specific to the data you provided and wouldn't generalise well, but here you are:

```
import re

teststring="Benchmark\r\n\tRunning for engine innodb\r\n\tAverage number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMinimum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tMaximum number of seconds to run all queries: 0.374 seconds\r\n\tNumber of clients running queries: 1\r\n\tAverage number of queries per client: 2"
prog = re.compile(".*Average number of seconds to run all queries: (\d+\.\d+) seconds.*", re.DOTALL)
result = prog.match(teststring)
print result.group(1)
```

And the output:

```
macbook:Downloads joeyoung$ python regextest.py 
0.374
```